# How can I upload file in a webform field through an API using Postman?

Tags: webforms

I created a webform with a File element called *attach_resume_cv* inside it. I want to create an API for uploading the files in that webform.
In my_module.routing.yml file I created next route:

```
my_module.webform:
  path: '/api/webform_submission/{webform_id}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\WebformController::webformSubmission'
    _title: 'Homepage'
    webform_id: ''
  methods: [ POST ]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
  options:
    no_cache: 'TRUE'
```

In Controller I have next method:

```
public function webformSubmission(Request $request, $webform_id)
{
    $values['webform_id'] = $webform_id;
    $postData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    foreach ($postData as $key => $data) {
        $values['data'][$key] = $data;
    }

    $webform = Webform::load($values['webform_id']);

    if (!$webform) {
        return new JsonResponse('Form not found', 400);
    }

    if (!WebformSubmissionForm::isOpen($webform)) {
        return new JsonResponse('Form is not available', 400);
    }

    // Validate submission.
    $validateErrors = WebformSubmissionForm::validateFormValues($values);

    // Check there are no validation errors.
    if (!empty($validateErrors)) {
        return new JsonResponse($validateErrors, 400);
    }

    // Submit values and get submission ID.
    WebformSubmissionForm::submitFormValues($values);
    return new JsonResponse('Success');
}
```

The problem is how to send files in webform. I tried in **postman** with body set as form-data, but $request->getContent() is empty.

Note: I am using Drupal 10

Comment: I've found a solution for this problem.
When it's needed to upload a file to a webform, there are needed two requests:
1) a request to upload the file which returns a fid 
2) a request including the fid for creating the submission to the webform